# A question on diffeomorphisms of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry

we know that any vector field $X$ on a smooth manifold $M$  generated the 1-parameter group $\phi_t$ ( the locally diffeomorphisms).

**My question:**  Are the locally diffeomorphisms on the manifold $M$ generated by a vector field on $M$?

Thanks

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to parse your question. Do you mean to ask "Is every 1-parameter group of diffeomorphisms $\phi_t$ the flow of some (complete) vector field?" In which case the answer is yes (differentiate $\phi_t$ with respect to $t$ at $0$); this is usually why people say the space of vector fields is the Lie algebra of the space of diffeomorphisms of a compact manifold.

Comment: What is a "locally diffeomorphism"?